# htaccess: Issue with RewriteCond -f (if file exists)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having a rough day into Apache's *.htaccess* manipulation methods and it seems I hit a wall.
My code intends to redirect all requests to `/index.php` just **except** for file requests, simple as that. I've been fairly reading other people's examples and documentation on every relatable statements and options to replicate the desired behavior.

So far this is the code:

```
RewriteEngine on

# If a requested file exists, rewrite route to the file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME} [L]

# If a requested file does not exist, rewrite route to index.php, works even if none was requested
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L,QSA]
```

So far this is working properly, I can create virtual paths with my PHP controllers and still validate queries thanks to `QSA`.

The unexpected, though, comes when I decided to log the `REQUEST_URI` for each time `/index.php` was being called, to find that by trying to acces a file that does NOT exist, it's logging a call to `/index.php`, and at this point I don't know any techniques to apply a condition to this case.

My question in a single sentence is: How can I implement such a `RewriteCond` that validates if what is being requested is a file, rather than if it exists?

In addition, since it's my first time manually controlling URI requests, is there any security measures or strong suggestions I should take in account when using this rules in *.htaccess*?

Comment: `if what is being requested is a file, rather than if it exists`... If it is a file, then it exists. In the opposite, if somethings exists, then it can either be a file or a folder. The `-f` condition means `if a file exists`. Also, you said `to find that by trying to acces a file that does NOT exist, it's logging a call to /index.php`. Which is the expected behavior, from your rules. That said, your question is quite unclear as I'm not able to understand what you want. You should try to re-phrase

Comment: Your first RewriteCond/-Rule combo there is just superfluous. Serving the content of an existing file (or passing it on to the configured handler), is the default behavior of Apache to begin with - you don’t need to re-implmenent that yourself. The negative condition before the second rule prevents it from working for any requests that match onto an existing file to begin with.